# Natural Spline Interpolation in R

Tags: splines, interpolation

I am trying to construct a natural cubic spline interpolation using R and test it with a Runge test function. I have implemented the following code; however, the interpolation is not passing through the original y-values of the knots. Based on my understanding of cubic spline, the first condition is that Sj(xj) = f(xj) and Sj(xj+1) = f(xj+1) for j= 0, 1, .. n-1, meaning the spline should interpolate all the given knots.

[image]

library(ggplot2)
library(splines)

#Create data
x <- seq(-1, 1, length.out = 201)
y <- runge(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

## Create knots

knots_3 <- quantile(x, probs = c(1/4, 2/4, 3/4))
knots_5 <- quantile(x, probs = c(1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5))
knots_10 <- quantile(x, probs = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1))

## Construct natural spline with 3 knots

spline_fit_3 <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots = knots_3))
pred_3 <- predict(spline_fit_3, data.frame(x =x))
error_3 <- max(abs(pred_3 - y))
cat("Maximum Absolute Error with 3 Knots:", error_3, "\n")

## Construct natural spline with 5 knots

spline_fit_5 <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots = knots_5))
pred_5 <- predict(spline_fit_5, data.frame(x = x))
error_5 <- max(abs(pred_5 - y))
cat("Maximum Absolute Error with 5 Knots:", error_5, "\n")

## Construct natural spline with 10 knots

spline_fit_10 <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots = knots_10))
pred_10 <- predict(spline_fit_10, data.frame(x = x))
error_10 <- max(abs(pred_10 - y))
cat("Maximum Absolute Error with 10 Knots:", error_10, "\n")

## Plot Runge function and natural splines

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_line(color = "navy", size = 1) +
geom_line(aes(y = pred_3), color = "green", size = 1) +
geom_line(aes(y = pred_5), color = "red", size = 1) +
geom_line(aes(y = pred_10), color = "orange", size = 1) +
ylim(0, 1) +
labs(title = "Natural Splines with 3, 5, and 10 Knots", x = "x", y = "y") +
theme_bw()